# One sided limits of $\left[ \frac{1}{x} \right]$ and $\left(\left[\frac{1}{x} \right]\right)^{-1} $

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $[x]$ be the largest integer which is $\leq x$.

I am supposed to find all $a$ for which both one sided limits of
$(a)\quad \left[ \dfrac{1}{x} \right]$
$(b)\quad \dfrac{1}{\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right]} $
exists as $x$ aproaches $a$.

$(a)$
I think that $\lim_{x\to a^+}\left[ \dfrac{1}{x} \right]$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-}\left[ \dfrac{1}{x} \right]$ exists for all $a$, including $a=0$, because
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left[ \dfrac{1}{x} \right] = \infty,\quad$ Just as for $\dfrac{1}{x}$
$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left[ \dfrac{1}{x} \right] = -\infty,\quad$ Just as for $\dfrac{1}{x}$

But the answer says that no one-sided limit exists for $a=0$, Is this correct?

$(b)$
In the case of $\dfrac{1}{\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right]} $ I thought that as long as $\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right]\neq 0$ both one sided limits would exist, so $a< 1$, because if $a \geq 1$ and $x$ approaches $a$ from the right,    $\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right] = 0 $ and so $\dfrac{1}{\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right]} $ would be undefined. However, the answer says that both one-sided limits exists only for $|a|<1$ and $a=1$. I do not understand this at all. As explained above I do not think the case $a=1$ has a right limit. Furthermore, I think every $a<0$ should have both one-sided limits because if $a< -1$, then $\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right] = -1$
no matter if $x$ approaches $a$ from the left or the right. So both the right and left limit should be $-1$.

If $a=-1$ then

$\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right] = -1$ or $\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right] = -2$
depending on from which direction x approaches $-1$. But in both cases there should be a left and right limit for $\dfrac{1}{\left[\dfrac{1}{x} \right]} $ as $x$ approaches $a$, namely $-1$ and $-\dfrac{1}{2}$

So can someone tell me if it is me or the book who is wrong?

Comment: In some languages, $\infty$ counts as "does not exist". Therefore, nobody is wrong.

Comment: Well, the book is in english, I'm reading Spivak. But this should not matter in $(b)$ does it?

Comment: "Languages" not as in "spoken natural languages" but "technical jargon".

Comment: Your definition of $[x]$ is unprecise, $0$ would match for all positive $x$.

Comment: @Henrik Oops, Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my definition.

Comment: I think Kenny Lau is right about part (a) because $\infty$ is not a specific value, so the limit does not exist.  However, I think  you are right about part (b).  I don't see how a right-hand limit can exist for $a=1$ because there are no values for $a$ to take greater than $1$ within the domain of the expression on which a limit can operate.  For $a<-1$ since this is the greatest integer function and we are no longer putting $0$ in the denominator, I think these limits should exist.

Comment: @hampadampadoo Just a correction and simplification of my previous comment.  For part (b), as I see it, if $a<1$ then both sided limits exist.  If $a=1$ then only the left-sided limit exists.  I agree with you about part (b).

Comment: @FrankHubeny Thank you so much for your input!